# The Saarthal Amulet does not show up in my inventory

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I have started the "Under Saarthal" quest and once I remove the amulet from the door and get trapped, it does not show up in my inventory.  I have re-loaded several times with no luck.  In one case I even reloaded to the start of entering the quest and then went off and completed other quests and sold stuff etc. but when I returned to the quest, the same issue occurred at the exact same point.  Again, I have reloaded but to no avail.  I have confirmed that I am not looking for the wrong item, it is simply not in my inventory. This issue is preventing me from progressing the Mage's and Forbidden Legend questlines.  Any ideas?

Comment: No idea, but try to install [SkyUI mod](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=3863) it fix lots of issues related to inventory and works fine for me even without the Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE) - it will show you big warning but so far the game work flawlessly and my inventory look much better..

Comment: Also, if you run it in PC you can spawn this item in your inventoty by typing this in the console (activated by pressing the `~` character): `player.additem 000233D0 1` (never done that personally but it should work. Use only as last resort as it's pretty much cheating)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Skyrim. If you're on PC I would recommend you download the "Unofficial Skyrim Patch" as it fixes a lot of these bugs.

Again, if you're on PC you can add the item to your inventory by typing:

```
player.additem 000233D0 1
```

This should add the amulet to your inv, and the quest should go on as usual! :)

[Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19)

Answer (score 3):

I might be 3 years late, but I found a solution for myself.
I have encountered the exact same thing, annoying as warm sticky fudge.
No site could provide me the help I needed so I forgot about the whole thing, still freaking annoyed.
I could not add the item cause it would not appear in any way in my inventory.
And then it came to me, I solved once a bug by clearing all my bounties, and so I did that and bam.
I had 2 saarthal amulets in my invent (cause I tried 2 times to spawn it in) went back to saarthal, it was a bit awkward for a moment but now I finally have finished this fudging quest.
Hope this still helps

*Lazy person from the future*